# Maven YUI compress javascript

Tags: javascript, maven, yui-compressor

I'm trying to set up YUI compressor so that each time I build a war to deploy, it minifies my JS and reversions it for cachebusting. I've managed to get it so the minified files are available with the maven version as a suffix, but the original files are also still there, plus all my hrefs need updating every time I build (and locally I still want to be using the originals). Can anyone suggest how to resolve this?

Here's what I have for the plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/farbtastic/*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/jquery.js</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.css</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <suffix>.${version}</suffix>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compress</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Version**

1.1 is quite old. We use 1.3.2

**locally I still want to be using the originals**

You should be using [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) for this. You should have two profiles (or may be more).

- One for Development/Local
- One for Production/Release/UAT etc (only this will contain the minimize plugin)

This is something we implemented and is working very well for a long time:Please try this way(note - see the stuff in the **war plugin** as well, below, it's very important. You might need to change the **targetPath** for the minimized):

```
<profile>
    <id>Production</id>
    .......
    .......
 <plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compress</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <!-- Show warnings decided on value of variable set in each profile -->
        <jswarn>${yuiCompression.warn}</jswarn>
        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/minimized</webappDirectory>
        <excludes>
                <exclude>**/farbtastic/*</exclude>
                <exclude>**/jquery.js</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.css</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
        <dependentWarExcludes>....</dependentWarExcludes>
        <warSourceExcludes>....</warSourceExcludes>
        <packagingExcludes>....</packagingExcludes>
        <packagingExcludes>....</packagingExcludes>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}/minimized</directory>
                <targetPath>/</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Let me know if it works.

**Issue of wanting file version numbers and having the hrefs update to point at the latest version**

I guess by this you mean by versioning for cache control (Basically to make sure always the new js/css is loaded on release?). This plugin doesnt do that. How will your code knows which version to use?

We had implemented this using a custom Tag lib: After that our Js/Css declaration looks like this:

```
<custom:ScriptTag src="/js/xyz.js"></custom:ScriptTag>
<custom:CssTag rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/someStyle.css"/>
```

And the compiled/rendered jsp looks like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/4112-13178/xyz.js' ></script>
<link type='text/css' href='/style/4112-13178/someStyle.css'  rel='stylesheet' />
```

**4112-13178** in between is the release-svnversion.

And once this is referenced an url rewrite filter (based on [Tuckey](http://org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter) or Apache mod_rewrite if you use apache in the front) rewrites this to:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/xyz.js' ></script>
```

when requested by the browser to the server.

**Solution 2 - versioning (With YUI plugin but Without URLRewrite)**

- You can add the version to the js using the YUI plugin.
- Then store the version number in a property file.
- Write a custom taglib(like explained above) which renders with that version no as given in the solution above

Advantage of this solution is that you don't need an url rewrite, but still would need a custom taglib.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a go at this now. Is a profile necessary if I'm just running locally through eclipse?

Comment: Profiles is the standard/cleanest way I guess.

Comment: This sort of works - but it doesn't address the issue of wanting file version numbers and having the hrefs update to point at the latest version

Comment: @Abby - Please see my updated answer. If you are happy and it works please feel free to accept/upvote.

Comment: Thanks again. I've still got the same issues though: when generating compressed files with version, the originals are still there, and the jsps still point to the originals. Your suggestions have worked, but not achieved what I'm after.

Comment: @Abby - Mate, Have you checked my update - "Issue of wanting file version numbers and having the hrefs update to point at the latest version". YUI plugin doesn't support your versioning. It only supports compressing the js/resources. Have a look at my updated answer on how we achieved versioning of js/css files.

Comment: ok - so I basically need to stick with having the version suffix as I already had, and use a different technology to remove the old files and replace the new versions in the html

Comment: @Abby - Yes, because your jsp's don't know the version right? Instead of using Tuckey filter(I'd recommend you to use Apache mod_rewrite, if you use Apache in the front). I'll update the answer with this as well.

Comment: @Abby - I added a solution 2 (Solution 2 - versioning) which you can use the YUI plugin and a Taglib but without a URLRewrite. Hope this helps.